Removing a DC offset with TL431
I have an electrical signal (output of ACS712), which is a sum of 2.5 constant voltage and an informative part, which is between 0 v and 0.25 v. I need to subtract 2.5 from said signal and decided to use TL431 for this purpose. Can you please explain me how I should do it or which other means I should use for it and why? I'm quite new to electronics, so I may not know about some widespread solution. My only restrictions are voltage sources as I don't want to use another DC source only for this offset and I'd prefer something precise and cheap.

What is causing the DC offset? If you can get access to that node, it would be better to make a differential measurement than to blindly subtract a fixed (more or less) value.

What bandwidth (frequency) or shape does your "informative signal" have? What is the source impedance of the "2.5V+informative" signal?

I cannot access a node which makes this offset as it is how ACS712 works. It is a current sensor, which output voltage corresponds to input current. Actually, it is bipolar and I use only one half of it's current interval but all ACS7XX have at least 0.5 v DC offset, even unipolar ones. So I decided to use ACS712.

Do you have a negative power supply available? If you do, you can do it with a TL431, a resistor, and no other parts required. Otherwise you'll need an op amp and some extra resistors (not a big deal--just a few more parts).

Frequency is 5kHz, output resistance of ACS712 is 1-2 Ω.

Also note that the output of the ACS712 is ratiometric, meaning that the offset is not actually a precise 2.5 V--it's actually a precise ½ Vcc, so any error on your Vcc is also error in the offset. So actually, doing a differential measurement against a precise voltage divider is probably the way to go.

I don't have a negative DC source, and I'd like to avoid adding it only for this purpose. I also tried differential amplifier scheme in simulation program, but it seems quite complicated considering resistor divider I need to get 2.5 v from my 5 v supply and also it divides signal on op-amp input by two, what could lead to more noise.

ACS712 has only one output. Should I use two this sensors for a differential measurement?

@user403613 No, just generate a reference voltage via a resistor divider on Vcc.

So I should use a voltage subtractor circuit with an op-amp? Won't it be noisy due to diving whole signal by 2?

What will be the circuit following this DC subtraction? Is some amplification required?

After subtraction I use non-inverting op-amp.

What are you measuring it with? Please show a schematic of your broader system (sensor, signal conditioning, what's reading it e.g. op-amps, controller, MCU, ADC, etc.).

I do not recommend that you use a TL431 to subtract the DC offset of the output signal. The ACS712 datasheet states (several times) that the DC offset is \$\frac{V_{CC}}{2}\$, referring to this as "ratiometric".
A fixed +2.5V reference will stay +2.5V as the power supply voltage fluctuates, but the ACS712's DC output offset will always be half of \$V_{CC}\$, which will rise and fall with the supply. If you wish the offset to become zero, then you must subtract exactly what the ACS712 adds, which is half of \$V_{CC}\$.
So, technically, the only voltage source you need to subtract can be obtained with two identical resistors across the supply, to get \$\frac{V_{CC}}{2}\$.
You may need some means of adjustment of this because it won't be exactly half, due to manufacturing differences from IC to IC. However, it should be a "set and forget" adjustment, since once you've set the exact fraction (close to one-half) to match the ACS712, both the ACS712 IC's internal voltage divider and your own external one will rise and fall in unison with the supply.
Whether you even need to (or should) perform the subtraction is entirely dependent on how you process the signal; what comes next. Are you measuring with an ADC, and processing this data digitally? If so, then consider this: if the ADC's positive reference is \$V_{CC}\$, then you can connect the ACS712 output directly to the ADC input. The ADC's idea of 2.5V will be ratiometric too, rising and falling with \$V_{CC}\$ exactly in unison with the ACS712's "ratiometric" 2.5V offset.
Also, since the ACS712 can measure negative currents too, an output potential below +2.5V is as valid and possible as outputs above that mid-way point. By subtracting 2.5V to obtain a signal centered about 0V, you have to ensure that the subsequent circuitry can work with inputs of 0V and lower. Keep in mind that op-amps with a single supply (i.e. their negative supply pin is connected to 0V) mostly cannot work with negative inputs, or even inputs that approach 0V. Absolutely no op-amp with a single supply can get its output down to 0V, including the ones claiming to have a "rail-to-rail" output. Many can't even output lower than +1V, like the TL081.
Therefore, in general if you use op-amps with input signals down to 0V, you have to take great care to choose the correct model. If you require that op-amp also output 0V (or negative), then I'm afraid you need to provide it with a negative supply.
All that said, here's a circuit using a single op-amp that will subtract a slightly adjustable \$\frac{V_{CC}}{2}\$ from the ACS712 output. It inverts the signal, but to compensate you just swap the IP+ and IP− inputs of the ACS712:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
As stated above, notice that this op-amp needs a negative supply in order to output 0V or lower.

Whoops, s/DAC/ADC/?

@TimWilliams Yeah - changed it! Brain fart!

@TimWilliams did you just pipe me through sed LOL?

I don't even use *nix, but have seen it used as an expression often enough, lol. Also that would only match the first instance so it needs a "find all" qualifier or something, but now I have to look up a regex tutorial :^)

@TimWilliams in any case, it got me laughing, so thanks for that

I don't use ADC and measuring current will always be positive. Thank you for your reply.
